# PHP Extract HTML content by HTML parse get null object

Tags: php, html

I am trying to extract content from a local HTML file. And I use the HTML parse method, however get nothing.

PHP code is as below:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("assets.html");
$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
foreach($tables as $table) {
   $content = $doc->saveHTML($table);
 }
echo $content;
```

Debug step by step,`$doc->loadHTML("assets.html")` return `true`,and got `DOMNodeList::__set_state(array(
))` for `$tables` .

The part of assets.html is as below:

```html
                                 <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" id="manage" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            新增
                                            <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="#" id="newassets">增加资产</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#" id="newdetail">增加明细</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                   </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteassets" value="" >删除</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="modifyassets" value="" >修改</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="lend-lease" value="" >领用</button>
                                </div>

                                  <div class="dataTable_hr_info">
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" action="" id="assetsInfo">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                                          <th data-field="pr" >序号</th>
                                          <th data-field="category">资产类别</th>
                                          <th data-field="name" >资产名称</th>
                                          <th data-field="model">型号</th>
                                          <th data-field="unit">单位</th>
                                          <th data-field="count">数量</th>

                                        </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                     </table>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `$doc` has the right document in it, that it loaded correctly? Does this code produce any errors in the log?

Comment: I just check $doc->loadHTML("assets.html") return true. How can I check if it's loaded correctly? Didn't find error info.

Comment: I think raideance has the right idea here. Maybe it parsed that string literally as if that was the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading HTML from a file so use: `$doc->loadHTMLFile("assets.html");` instead of `$doc->loadHTML("assets.html");`

You should get data inside `$content` after that.

Comment: as your solution, I get the correct content in HTML5. But some HTML file is under HTML 4.0 version. After loadHTMLFile, got error info about "Unexpected end tag". But I checked manually I think all the tags closed properly. Do you know if the HTML parse support HTML4?

Answer (score 0):

Found some mistake in your code.

> 1 : You can not use loadHTML method for load html.
>
> 2 : In your HTML file some tags are not properly closing.

Check below code,

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('assets.html'));
    $tables = $dom->documentElement->getElementsByTagName('table');
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $content = $dom->saveHTML($table);
    }
    echo $content;
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" id="manage" data-toggle="dropdown">
            新增
    <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="newassets">增加资产</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="newdetail">增加明细</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteassets" value="" >删除</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="modifyassets" value="" >修改</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="lend-lease" value="" >领用</button>
<div class="dataTable_hr_info">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" action="" id="assetsInfo">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                <th data-field="pr" >1</th>
                <th data-field="category">2</th>
                <th data-field="name" >3</th>
                <th data-field="model">4</th>
                <th data-field="unit">5</th>
                <th data-field="count">6</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```